# Saving a password in wordpress safely

Tags: mysql, wordpress, passwords, storage

I'm trying to save a password in a wordpress plugin. Currently I thought I'd create a mysql table and store the users password in there (it's going to be used to send SOAP requests to an api).
I wonder if there's a safer way of storing passwords than to add them in a table, since they would be readable if a possible attacker gains access to a database. The issue however is that, since it's going to be used to make api requests, an md5 hashed version of a password or something similar won't do.
Is there a more secure way of storing a password specific to Wordpress than having it in a database table?

Comment: Short answer: no. You can encrypt it having the key in a file, or PHP code. If an attacker just manages to get a copy of your database, at least the password would not be leaked. If everything (file system and database) is compromised, the password cannot be stored in a safe fashion without user interaction upon each API request.

Comment: In that case I think I would need to find another way of doing this. Thank you for your answer @Damocles.